# How do I call a variable from my javascript in my php file?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a piece of code (JSFiddle link below), that generates a picture based on the radio button clicked. I would like to send the name of the resulting image to a form so it can be sent to a different page (payPal checkout). I can't seem to get it to work and I'm looking for help. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/YRWKH/

Comment: You have a document.ready inside a window.load, why?

Comment: @Musa because I am not a skilled Javascript guy. It worked which is all that I wanted.

Comment: @RaymondAblack, don't edit your questions to say you've reached some limit. If you have an issue like this, check whether there's an answer on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or ask a question there.

Answer (score 1):

First, add a field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="some_name" value="" id="the-hidden-field" />
```

Then, in your `updateImage()` function, you can do:

```
var src = "images/" + BodyColor + InsertColor + ".jpg";
$("#FinalImage").attr('src' src);
$('#the-hidden-field').val(src);
```

Now your hidden field has the same value as the `src` attribute on the image itself, and of course the hidden field will be passed to the server as would any other field.

Comment: I could not get that to work. No value went to #the-hidden-field

Comment: I tweaked your code a little and got it to work! Thanks so much for the push!

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input. onclick of the radio button, set the value to the path to the image, then on post, just simply $_POST to grab the image name.